# What is our stance on questions specific to one airport? On-topic or off-topic as too specific?

Tags: discussion, scope, closed-questions

What is our stance on questions specific to one airport? On-topic or off-topic as too specific?

I'm asking as I saw that there exists some questions specific to one airport (probably why many airports have their own tag), but the question [What percentage of international flights departing from Manila are cancelled due to Duterte's lockdown on Metro Manila from 2020-03-15 to 2020-04-14?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/q/154940/1810) got closed by a moderator for two reasons, one of the two being:

> You could ask this as a separate question for each airport in many countries.

Which means questions specific to one airport should be closed.
So I'm confused. Please clarify the scope policy.

Answer (score 6):

Questions about one airport can be fine. How do I get from Venice airport to actual Venice? Are there restaurants after security at [small airport]? Yes, in theory someone could come and ask variants of the same question for every airport, but since we expect questions to be specific problems you really face, that isn't going to happen.

However for a worldwide issue like the current virus, things are different. Suddenly everyone **is** asking about every airport. It's better to have one question that summarizes things, perhaps with one answer for each large region.

Comment: Precisely. This is the perfect situation that warrants a canonical q/a gathering all the up to date information.